# cross domain, and allow origin are set but still no response

Tags: php, angularjs, cross-domain, ionic-framework

I have my server that return data, and I give this response on the code:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo 'the response';
```

now when I use the chrome dev tools to check the response I see that: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is set to "*" so that is good.

```
The response from the server:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 16 Oct 2014 07:45:34 GMT
Server:nginx/1.1.19
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IlhhdTlOSHJMYmlnWm44bE1TTnBYXC9uMUhZQ1wvN21UWFZzMWlHRm5lb3ZtND0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6InZSZjJZNFpQaldNblJiT05iK08wK3VTQXJRQXBSZ0paOXdIdjJyOGNPZFlaOUZNNVwvOVYzalBnaGVSUkc2YWF2THBGcnQwVHhocUFHQyt6S296bmZKZz09IiwibWFjIjoiYjQxZjhlYjI4ZGJkMTk1NWZjZmYyNWI3MTg2YmU4NTM3Y2MwMDNiOTA3YmQxZmNkYjVhZmUwOTkyYzQ0ZGRiMiJ9; expires=Thu, 16-Oct-2014 09:45:34 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

but when I try to access it with my angular project, I get this bug:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://MYSITE.co/api/posts/all. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this package:

github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

How do you try to access the resource? For an iframe as well as for usage of HTML-templates  I had to call the $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist() method.

```
angular.module('myApp', [ ])
    .config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
        $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
           // Allow same origin resource loads.
           'self',
           // Allow loading from our assets domain.  Notice the difference between * and **.
           'http://MYSITE.co/**']);
    });
```

From the angular documentation: "This allows one to get/set the whitelists and blacklists used to ensure that the URLs used for sourcing Angular templates are safe."